# No data returned in response but api is sending data in return statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am working on .net core web api and i have come across an issue where data is being sent as a model class but still in swagger no data is found in reponse i just see

```
{}
```

here is the screen shot of data returned by api [image]

here is the response in [image: swagger]

I gone through so much possibilities on stack and havent found any issue related to this

Comment: Post code and responses as *text*, not images. Images can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled. Obfuscating parameter names isn't securing anything, it's only making it harder to understand the problem. Have you actually tried to call that URL directly? Did you type `https://.../1/1` in a browser to see what you get?

Comment: The code itself is missing. Perhaps all those properties are marked with `JsonIgnore` so none of them gets serialized? Perhaps the action's return type isn't `JsonModel` but something else? Perhaps the screenshot shows a different method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue i had been through was that i had not made setter and getters for the object returned as it was returning multiple ienumerable objects. so setter and getters solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a mismatch between the request method (GET,POST...) and the way you are trying to access the returned data.

Comment: no both the sides are get method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).